# Variable >=(range)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to change what map is displayed when a requirement is met. I want to use a range on the elif statements to save some time.

curmov changes every turn in a range of 0-31

map1(),2,3 are ASCII maps

```
def curmap():
    global curmov
    if curmov <=9:
        mapNow = map1()
    elif curmov (10,24):
        mapNow = map2()
    elif curmov (25,30):
        mapNow = map3()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what `curmov(10,24)` is supposed to mean, but I suspect it's this:

```
10 <= curmov < 24
```

… or, equivalently:

```
curmov in range(10, 24)
```

(Note to any future readers using Python 2.x: don't use the second one. In Python 2.x, that will create a list of 14 numbers just to compare them one by one against `curmov`, which would be silly. In Python 3.x, it creates a `range` object, which can handle this instantaneously.)

---

Note that I'm using `10 <= curmov < 24`. That's called a "half-open" range—the left half is "closed", because `10` is part of the range, while the right half is "open", because `24` is not. In Python, `range(10, 24)` checks the same thing, because all ranges are half-open in Python. If you want an "open" range (neither `10` nor `24` count as part of it) or a "closed" range (both `10` and `24` count), the first one is easy to change by just changing the `<=` or `<` appropriately; the second one, you have to add a `+1` or `-1` somewhere.

---

However, if your ranges aren't supposed to overlap or have any gaps, it may be simpler and more readable (and even more robust, because there's no chance for accidental off-by-one overlaps and gaps) to just do this:

```
if curmov <= 9: blah
elif curmov <= 24: bleh
elif curmov <= 30: blih
else: bluh
```

Comment: (10,24) is supposed to be the range

Comment: @Chanヨネ: What does "be the range" mean? You want to check if `curmov` is within that range? Is it closed, half-open, or open? Your question title says `>=(range)`, which is… pretty confusing.

Comment: yes want to check if curmov is within that range. I dont know what you meen by "closed, half-open, or open"

Comment: @NickRusso: Rejected your edit because the `range` check is _not_ more expensive for large ranges. The answer even directly explains that.

Comment: The OP's intent is not entirely clear, but I suspect this should be `<= 24` and `range(10, 25)` to match the `elif` chain at the bottom.

Comment: @abarnert: no problem, I should have used a comment. I hadn't read your update about Python 2 vs 3 when I posted the change. I'm still used to using xrange instead of range since I don't use Python 3 much. So range objects are fancier than just "a generator" -- they also have something like membership checks? neat!

Comment: @Chanヨネ: I've added a paragraph to explain closed, half-open, and open. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @NickRusso: Yes, Python 3's `range` is a sort of "smart view on a virtual list", not just an iterator. Which also means you can do `3 in range(1, 100, 2)` and it'll work, which would be more painful to write with chained comparisons. There are other smart views, like `dict.keys()` (which acts like a `set`).

Comment: @GregHewgill: I'm honestly not sure; if you read it as all closed ranges, he's missing 31, but if you read it as half-open ranges, he's missing 24. I think it's more important to get the OP to realize the difference and figure out what he wants than to try to guess what he wants for him…

Comment: @abarnert everything makes more sense thanks for your help guys!